# Magento 2 - REST API - Property "0" does not have corresponding setter

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.1.11

I made an API route that will take an array of `CartItemInterface` objects and modify them with just one call (to reduce multiple calls). The problem I am facing is that it is giving me this error in the logs:

> Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface".

I do have a feeling the API is thinking that part of the request data is just a single object, not an array of objects hence thinking `"0"`, which might be the array index `0`.

**{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/foo/carts/mine/items" method="PUT">
    <service class="{Vendor}\{Module}\Api\Magento_Quote\CartItemRepositoryInterface" method="saveAsUser" />

    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>

    <data>
        <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

**{Vendor}/{Module}/Api/Magento_Quote/CartItemRepositoryInterface**

```
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Api\Magento_Quote;

interface CartItemRepositoryInterface
{

    /**
     * Add/update an array of cart items
     *
     * @param int $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface[] $cartItems
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface[]
     */
    public function saveAsUser($cartId, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItems);
```

**Request Data**

```
{
    "cartItems": [
        0: "--Cart Item--",
        1: "--Cart Item--"
    ]
}
```

I had looked around for questions similar in nature:

[Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213239/property-0-does-not-have-corresponding-setter-in-class-magento-sales-api-data)

But the question did not have any solid answers.

[How to set Interfaces for custom module API creation in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160455/how-to-set-interfaces-for-custom-module-api-creation-in-magento2)

Tried something similar to this question:

> you cant sent an array at very first object.

I modified the request data to:

```
{
    "cartId": '123',
    "cartItems": [
        0: "--Cart Item--",
        1: "--Cart Item--"
    ]
}
```

Still getting the same error.